# fft in swift's accelerate giving unexpected results

Tags: swift, fft

Please forgive if this feels repeated. I have exhausted the available examples for myself - and I am new in swift. I am trying to use the Fast Fourier Transform of Accelerate from swift. I have the following two functions that I arranged.

```
//both forward and inverse 
//direction for example FFT_FORWARD, FFT_BACKWARD
func fftBoth(_ _values : DSPDoubleSplitComplex, sz: Int, direction: Int)
 -> DSPDoubleSplitComplex{
    var values = _values;
    let LOG_N = vDSP_Length(log2(Float(sz)))
    let fftSetup: FFTSetupD = vDSP_create_fftsetupD(LOG_N, FFTRadix(kFFTRadix2))!
    vDSP_fft_zripD(fftSetup, &values, 1, LOG_N, FFTDirection(direction));

    vDSP_destroy_fftsetup(fftSetup)
    return values;
}

//simply change a double array to complex by placing - 
//the array in the real part and the imaginary array of zeros.
func getComplexFormat(inputSamples : [Double]) -> DSPDoubleSplitComplex{
    let samples = inputSamples;
    var sampleImag : [Double] = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: inputSamples.count)
    let realpPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>.allocate(capacity: samples.count);
    realpPointer.initialize(from: samples)
    let imagPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>.allocate(capacity: samples.count)
    imagPointer.initialize(from: sampleImag)
    return DSPDoubleSplitComplex(realp: realpPointer, imagp: &sampleImag)
}
var a : [Double] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
var aComplex = getComplexFormat(inputSamples: a);

var aFFT = fftBoth(aComplex, sz: a.count, direction: FFT_FORWARD)
print("--- a fft res ---");
for i in 0..<a.count/2{
    print("\(round(aFFT.realp[i])) + \(round(aFFT.imagp[i]))i");
}
print("--- /end ---");
```

When I run the above code, I get weird result. I am working on it on the playground and every time I run the code the printed fft results are different. I show two of the different outputs here.

```
 --- a fft res ---
20.0 + 0.0i
-4.0 + 0.0i
-4.0 + 0.0i
-4.0 + 0.0i
--- /end ---

--- a fft res ---
4.591849731813e+15 + 0.0i
3.24692808355458e+15 + 0.0i
-4.0 + 0.0i
-3.24692808355459e+15 + 0.0i
 --- /end ---
```

I wish to know where I am doing wrong. I appreciate the help. thanks.

**Note**

I have come to realise that the problem lies with passing `DSPDoubleSplitComplex` from one function to another. It seems to be lost sometimes.

Comment: What happens if you print `aComplex` in the same way? When you get unintentionally random output, it usually means that you are reading uninitialized memory.

Comment: `return DSPDoubleSplitComplex(realp: realpPointer, imagp: &sampleImag)`: the imaginary part here points to local data, if I understand correctly?